# How to select current date+1 from date picker popup, without using sendkeys

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Using selenium web-driver Java, I want to select current date+1 from date popup, I have seen other post related to date picker but they are related to current date only or else using sendkeys. I don't want to use sendkeys.
Below is the HTML code

```
    '<table id="dp_cal_calendar" class="calendar" classname="calendar" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 282px; left: 574px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="cells" classname="cells">
<thead class="caldayheading" classname="caldayheading">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="wkend" classname="wkend">20</td>
<td class="wkend" classname="wkend">21</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">22</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">23</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">24</td>
<td class="wkday curdate" classname="wkday curdate">25</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>'
```

Comment: That completly depends on the datepicker we are talking about. In the end a datepicker is also just html and you need to find out the xpath/css rules that allows you to select aka click on the next day.

Comment: Except current date, css path is same for every date, and if I will use xpath every day it will vary, so it will not work in that case.

Comment: Regarding CSS, that's exactly the kind of implementation detail that's relevant to the question and ought to be stated so people don't assume otherwise when answering. And if your xpath varies day-by-day, then the solution likely involves dynamically constructing an xpath.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ur date picker calendar is in table format 
you can use:

```
 public void checkDate(){

    String currentDate = null;
    int counter=0;

    WebElement tab = driver.findElement(By.id("tabid"));

    List<WebElement> rows= tab.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for(int i =0;i<=rows.size()-1;i++){



        List<WebElement> columns=rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        Iterator itr = columns.iterator();


        while(itr.hasNext()){

            WebElement we=(WebElement) itr.next();

            if(we.getText().equals(currentDate)){

                break;

            }

            counter=counter+1;
        }

    //element to be clicked is +1 to c

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(i) li:nth-child(counter+1)")).click();

    }
```

PS. This should serve your purpose but you need to handle the case when your current date is in last column of the table.

**UPDATE:**

```
 String currDate= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table#dp_cal_calendar table.cells td.wkday.curdate")).getText();

 int dateToBeSelected = Integer.parseInt(currDate) + //no of days you want to add ;

 WebElement currentDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='dp_cal_calendar']//table[@class='cells']//td[contains(text(),'"+String.valueOf(dateToBeSelected) +"')]")).click();
```

Comment: above code is not working showing error due to counter+1

Comment: PFB html code:
`<table id="dp_cal_calendar" class="calendar" classname="calendar" >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="cells" classname="cells">
<thead class="caldayheading" classname="caldayheading">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="wkend" classname="wkend">6</td>
<td class="wkend" classname="wkend">7</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">8</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">9</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">10</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">11</td>
<td class="wkday" classname="wkday">12</td>
</table>`

Comment: Can you post your error trace in your question body?

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector #dp_cal_calendar table.cells tbody tr td.wkday.curdate(counter+1) is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: change your cssSelector from `"#dp_cal_calendar table.cells tbody tr td.wkday.curdate(counter+1)"` to `"#dp_cal_calendar table.cells tbody tr td.wkday:nth-child(" + (counter+1) +")"`

Comment: Still getting same error. Is there any alternate solution so that I can select date in future as well as in past like current date+1 and current date-2.

Comment: You need to post your HTML code because the current one looks faulty to me bcoz there are no ending tbody tags

Comment: @swati : I've updated my answer; only use the updated part.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code but, I don't want to hard code date value in code as I need to run automation pack every week, then every time I need to change date according to current date. I am looking for generalise code which can auto pick date according to current date.

Comment: @swati : I've updated the UPDATE part, this way current date will be fetched from the GUI