# How to select a date in a datepicker 2 days from curreny date always with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I am automating script with Selenium Webdriver in java . I want to select  a date in a datepicker always +2 days from current date, I am using test NG framework.

Scenario is - every time you pick a date , it should be current day +2 days 
e.g if today is 28th it should select 30th

**Correct solution is as below**
 ///Get today's date by using function in java
      //It will store all the web elements in list 
 //add 2 day to today's date using calendar function in java
  //Once you have date use selenium sendkeys into the text box to select (today+2) date

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
Date dt = new Date();
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
cl.setTime(dt);;
cl.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
dt=cl.getTime();
String str = df.format(dt);
    System.out.println("the date today is " + str);


WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table//td"));
   el.sendKeys(str);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a date from date picker using Selenium webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398575/select-a-date-from-date-picker-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144111/handle-calender-using-selenium-webdriver/42144270#42144270

Comment: @Sim Check this out: [How to select current date+1 from date picker popup, without using sendkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764114/how-to-select-current-date1-from-date-picker-popup-without-using-sendkeys/41767044?noredirect=1#comment75401998_41767044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic answer:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
    String newDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```